# php mail script sending email but not sending variables in single quotes, mails same line from script and won't email if using double quotes

Tags: php, forms, email, variables

The script below will send an email upon submitting the form but the name from name is $name, the subject line is correct, it emails to the correct email address, the reply-to is $name and the email messages is the exact message with the variables not the form info.

If I use double quotes for the lines not working they then show up as "purple" varibales in dreamweaver but it doesn't send the email when submitting the form.

I'm clearly missing something but am new to this and frustrated lol. Really appreciate any help or point me to a better option for this form.

```
<?php
$errors = [];

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get POST data
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? strip_tags(trim($_POST['name'])) : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : '';
    $phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? strip_tags(trim($_POST['phone'])) : '';
    $location = isset($_POST['location']) ? trim($_POST['location']) : '';
    $date = isset($_POST['date']) ? strip_tags(trim($_POST['date'])) : '';
    $guests = isset($_POST['guests']) ? trim($_POST['guests']) : '';
    $type = isset($_POST['type']) ? strip_tags(trim($_POST['type'])) : '';
    $comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? strip_tags(trim($_POST['comment'])) : '';

    
    
    // Validate form fields
    if (empty($name)) {
        $errors[] = 'Name is empty';
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        $errors[] = 'Email is empty';
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] = 'Email is invalid';
    }

    if (empty($comment)) {
        $errors[] = 'Comment field is empty';
    }

    
    // If no errors, send email
    if (empty($errors)) {
        // Recipient email address (replace with your own)
        
        
        $to      = 'my@email.com';
        $subject = 'My Subject Line';
        $message = 'Name: $name \r\n Email: $email \r\n Phone: $phone \r\n Location: $location \r\n Date (mm/dd/yr): $date \r\n Estimated Guest Count: $guests \r\n Catering Type: $type \r\n Message: \r\n $comment \r\n';
        $headers = array(
            'From' => '$name <$email>',
            'Reply-To' => '$name <$email>',
            'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
        );

        


        // Send email
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            header( 'Location: ../contacted.html' ) ;
        } else {
            echo "Failed to send email. Please try again later.";
        }
    } else {
        // Display errors
        echo "The form contains the following errors:<br>";
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo "- $error<br>";
        }
    }
} else {
    // Not a POST request, display a 403 forbidden error
    header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
    echo "You are not allowed to access this page.";
}
?>
```

I have tried everything I can think of and find with no luck.

Comment: Variables are not interpolated in single-quoted strings, instead you get the literal string that was quoted. You want a double-quoted string like `echo "$name";` See [here](https://reqbin.com/code/php/08tym4bq/php-string-interpolation-example) for some examples.

Comment: Also escape sequences like `\r\n` are not processed in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks and that’s where I’m hung up. With single quotes I get the literal string and with double quotes the email never shows up in my inbox.